# CSS word-spacing property doesn't work after HTML minified with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have something similar to the following in my document:

```css
.batman {
  word-spacing: 100px;
}
.batman > div {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="batman">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>world</div>
</div>
```

Now, I run the html through the following php code to minify it before output:

```
ob_start(function($html) {return preg_replace('/>\s+</','><',$html);});

...html goes here...

ob_end_flush();
```

which, returns this to the browser:

```css
.batman {
  word-spacing: 100px;
}
.batman > div {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="batman"><div>hello</div><div>world</div></div>
```

So here is the problem:

When the html is on one line, the `word-spacing` css is gone, or should I say, ignored.

There is no 100px space between my two div's with "hello" and "world".

How can I preserve the `word-spacing` while also being able to keep code on one line, either actually typing it on one line myself, or running it through a minifier?

Or what change can be done to my simple minify script to make sure `word-spacing` still works.

Conditions: I do! need the divs to be inline-block.

Comment: it's because when the html is flattened into one line there is literally no space for it to work with, try adding a space to either the end of the first div, or the start of the second div

Comment: Word spacing applies to a sentence within the designated div. You are wrapping each word in its own div. Word spacing does not work like that. Your HTML should look like this after you process it if you want to use word spacing.

    <div class="batman">hello  world</div>

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` to create a blank space. --> Something like that:  `<div class="batman"><div>hello&nbsp;</div><div>world</div></div>`

Comment: I think your minifier is invalid. Instead of removing all spaces between elements, it should reduce it to a single space. There's a difference between `</div> <div>` and `</div><div>`. And collapsing whitespace will also be wrong if any of the elements are wrapped in an element with `white-space: pre` style.

Comment: yeah, think ill have to look at replacing the minifier

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that this is a hacky solution. Anyway, you can use a pesudo-element

```css
.batman div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.batman div:first-child {
  content: '';
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="batman"><div>hello</div><div>world</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a single space character after the first div for `word-spacing` to work in your minified HTML. No need to alter the PHP.

Just use a CSS pseudo-element with an escaped Unicode sequence for the space.

```css
.batman {
    word-spacing: 100px;
}
.batman > div {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.batman > div:first-child::after {
  content: "\00a0";
}
```

```html
<div class="batman"><div>hello</div><div>world</div></div>
```

Comment: thats a great idea, but i might have more than one child elements though. currently trying to apply ":after" that to each child, but making that space literally 0 in visible width. font-size 0? negative margin?..not getting it exact here.... so close :)

Comment: have a look at this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/apozPX  , the CSS for each row is the same, but first row is placed on one line.... need it to look just like the second row.

Comment: Currently on MS Edge. Both rows identical. Will check Chrome and FF later today.

Comment: thank you Michael. It works in MSIE 11, while Firefox 49 and vivaldi 1.2 shows different lines. like this: i.imgur.com/JQMkZ2F.jpg

Comment: Working on your codepen. So far, nothing I've tried with CSS has worked. Will let you know if there's a break through. It may actually be simpler to adjust the PHP.

Comment: I truly appreciate your help :)